# How to setup RSS feed to support Chapters?

Tags: rss

**This question is regarding JWPlayer 7.3.**

According to this JWPlayer article about Chapters (see very bottom), JW player has support for chapters from an RSS feed:

> Chapters can also be loaded as part of RSS feeds. See the RSS Feeds Reference for more info.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407454-adding-chapter-markers

Unfortunately, there are no details on what RSS data is parsed on the RSS page. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It does not use the rss file, but the vtt file, also used for subtitles.

So you have to create a chapters.vtt file, with this example content:

```
WEBVTT

Chapter 1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:01:00.000
First chapter

Chapter 2
00:01:00.000 --> 00:02:00.000
Second chapter
```

After you can setup the player:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("container");
playerInstance.setup({
  file: "video.mp4",
  tracks: [{
    file:'chapters.vtt',
    kind:'chapters'
  }],
});
```

The video will have chapters. That's all.

**UPDATE**
You can also use Chapters with playlist feeds, RRS or JSON files, this is a JSON example with 2 media files, and 2 chapters files:

setup player

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("container");
playerInstance.setup({
   playlist: "playlist.json"
});
```

playlist.json

```
[{
  "file": "myvideo_1.mp4",
  "title": "First Video",
   tracks: [{
    file:'chapters_1.vtt',
    kind:'chapters'
  }],
},
{
  "file": "myvideo_2.mp4",
  "title": "Second Video",
   tracks: [{
    file:'chapters_2.vtt',
    kind:'chapters'
  }],
}]
```

chapters_1.vtt

```
WEBVTT

Chapter 1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:01:00.000
First chapter first video

Chapter 2
00:01:00.000 --> 00:02:00.000
Second chapter first video
```

chapters_2.vtt

```
WEBVTT

Chapter 1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:01:30.000
First chapter second video

Chapter 2
00:01:30.000 --> 00:02:30.000
Second chapter second video
```

Comment: So the quote above is inaccurate, then? RSS feeds do not support chapters?

Comment: My goal here is to have a playlist with chapter support. This is for a podcast. I can use a json playlist instead of an rss feed if necessary, or an html playlist I suppose. Your example is not a playlist though.

Comment: Ok, there was a misunderstanding :-) so you have to configure your player with playlist: "playlist.json" and configuring the chapters.vtt into playlist.json. I've updated the answer